# Given $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, show that every vector $x$ in null space of $A$ is also in null space of $AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

For the null space equation $Ax = 0$ and for $A$ and $B$ having the same dimensions, I am currently trying to prove whether or not every vector x in $Nul(A)$ is also in $Nul(AB)$. Also trying to prove whether for every vector $x$ in $Nul(A)$ and is also in $Nul(BA)$. I have to use definite proofs, not specific examples. I have thought about the order of multiplying $A$ and $B$ and how they transform $x$ but I can't see how that helps in proving. I am pretty stuck here.

Comment: A $2\times 2$ counterexample *is* a definite proof. Try $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is in the nullspace of $A$, then it is certainly in the nullspace of $BA$ since
$$
BAx = B(Ax) = B0 = 0
$$
But not necessarily in the nullspace of $AB$. I'm not sure what you mean by wanting definite proofs, rather than 'specific examples' as giving a counterexample to the claim that $\ker(A)\subseteq \ker(AB)$ would absolutely constitute a definite proof.